# onmouseover and onmouseout error function is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to open a dropdown-menu using onmouseover and onmouseout.

```
<div id="adminDropdown" class="dropdown" dropdown>
    <a onmouseover="openDropdownMenu('adminDropdown')"
       onmouseout="closeDropdownMenu('adminDropdown')">
        Admin
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a>Submenu 1</a></li>
        <li><a>Submenu 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="userProfile" class="dropdown" dropdown>
        <a onmouseover="openDropdownMenu('userProfile')"
           onmouseout="closeDropdownMenu('userProfile')">
            Username
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a>Submenu 1</a></li>
            <li><a>Submenu 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

My javascript has the following code:

```
$rootScope.openDropdownMenu = (id: string) => {
   var dropdown = document.getElementById(id);
   dropdown.classList.add('open');
};

$rootScope.closeDropdownMenu = (id: string) => {
   var dropdown = document.getElementById(id);
   dropdown.classList.remove('open');
};
```

But everytime I mouse over the links it would give me a `Uncaught ReferenceError: openDropdownMenu is not defined` and the same with closeDropdownMenu function.

I have tried:

```
$rootScope.dropdown = document.getElementById('adminDropdown');
$rootScope.dropdown.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
   $rootScope.dropdown.classList.add('open');
});

$rootScope.dropdown.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
   $rootScope.dropdown.classList.remove('open');
});
```

But I want to be able to change the parameter id so I can use the same function more than once as I have more than one dropdown.

Can someone enlighten me on this error? Thanks.

Comment: You could use jQuery instead...

Comment: What is `$rootScope`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ngMouseover](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseover) and [ngMouseleave](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseleave) instead

```
<a ng-mouseover="openDropdownMenu('adminDropdown')"
   ng-mouseleave="closeDropdownMenu('adminDropdown')">
    ...
</a>
```

The functions will only be available when evaluated inside an angular scope.

Comment: Thanks! This is one of those moments when I just want to hit my head for making this silly mistake. :-)